# I keep getting error: First column TO DO is not mapped to work item type Task first state New

Tags: azure, devops, sprint

I'm trying to set up my taskboard in Sprint view. I am trying to configure/map the columns to show up on the sprint taskboard. However, whenever I try to save the columns I defined, I keep getting this error message and I'm unable to complete setting up my columns. What am I doing wrong? What is this error asking me to do?

I need to remove a few "states" columns like "resolved, active, new" but the messaging I got when trying to move that is I don't have sufficient admin access. So I'll get that and remove some states. It's too many. I only want 9 states/columns to show in sprint board.

[Error message in columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOTJw.png)

I wanted columns I added to show up on sprint taskboard view.